# Xcode keeps showing:-1: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2.Any solution?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode10, xcode10.1

When I install facebook SDK pods into my ios project, It says ":-1: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'FacebookCore')"

I am using swift 4.2 
any solution?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?  It sounds like you need to upgrade to 10.2 and change your project to Swift 5 in order to use that framework

Comment: i am using Xcode 10.1

Comment: FBSDK supports swift 4.2, 3.0

Comment: According to the error message you have that module is set as Swift 5, so you need Xcode 10.2

Comment: solved the issue without updating..thank you

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Change the podfile swift version like for any pod if you are getting this error
like

```
Select pods of your project
```

[image: Select pod of your project]

After then you follow the steps as described in the image and change the swift version for the pod 
    [image: next steps]

Comment: What if there is no attribute by that name "Swift Compiler - Language"

Comment: Every attribute have swift version , you can change the swift version

Comment: For those using source control this fix only works if you include the Pods/ folder in your repo.

Answer (score 12):

I am currently using Xcode 10.1. The "Targets" section is in another place of the interface.

[Xcode 10.1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccxOD.png)

Beyond that, the Ravi Ojha solution works fine as well.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps and change nay required pod version.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to update from xcode 10.0 to 10.3 which supports Swift 5.0