# Facebook login for Swift 4

Tags: facebook, swift4

I'm trying to install facebook SDK using swift 4 (xcode version 10.1) and it doesn't work. The error says

> 'SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'FacebookCore')'
>
> 'SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'FacebookLogin')'

Is there any way to fix this problem without upgrading the swift version to 5.0?

Comment: are you using pod 'FacebookCore' and 'FacebookLogin'?

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention the SDK i'm trying to install was both of them

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585598/8361802. It might help you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55366024/5461400